# Can't see WiFi SSID

Tags: wireless

I have installed 12.04.1 on Dell Latitude E6510
At work I could able connect to WiFi and it is OK
At home I use DSL WiFi modem router which works fine and I can connect thru Windows, Android phone etc. But Ubuntu doesn't even see SSID name. Only "my" SSID name :( I can see others

> 03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)

My wifi settings are WPA/WPA2 PSK

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recently had this problem and solved it changing the CHANNEL of my wifi router to 10, Looks like there were too many ssid's in my previous channel...